# Drag and Drop in JS: detect a file

Tags: javascript

I'm implementing a drag&drop in JS, it works but the detection of my file is quite bad (when the file is drag over the dropzone it isn't always detected).
Also i would like to click anywhere in the dropzone to activate my input it doesn't work either.

Here is my code and a link to my codePen to test it: https://codepen.io/ChloeMarieDom/pen/QWPLqNz?editors=0010

```js
// Variables
const dropzone = document.querySelector('.dropzone');
const filenameDisplay = document.querySelector('.filename');
const input = document.querySelector('.input');
const uploadBtn = document.querySelector('.upload-btn');
const syncing = document.querySelector('.syncing');
const done = document.querySelector('.done');
const upload = document.querySelector('.upload');
const line = document.querySelector('.line');


dropzone.addEventListener("dragover", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  dropzone.classList.add("dragover");
});

dropzone.addEventListener("dragleave", () => {
  dropzone.classList.remove("dragover");
});

dropzone.addEventListener("drop", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  dropzone.classList.remove("dragover");
  handleFiles(e.dataTransfer.files);
});

dropzone.addEventListener("dragenter", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  dropzone.classList.add("dragover");
});

dropzone.addEventListener("click", () => {
  input.click();
});

input.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
  const files = event.target.files;
  if (files.length > 0) {
    const fileName = files[0].name;
    document.querySelector('.filename').textContent = fileName;
    upload.style.display = 'none';
  }
});

dropzone.addEventListener('click', () => {
  input.click();
})

uploadBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const files = document.querySelector('.input').files;
  if (files.length > 0) {
    dropzone.style.transition = 'opacity 0.5s ease';
    syncing.style.transition = 'opacity 1s ease';
    dropzone.style.opacity = '0';
    syncing.style.opacity = '0.3';
    line.classList.add('active');
    uploadBtn.textContent = 'Uploading...';

    setTimeout(() => {
      done.style.transition = 'opacity 1s ease';
      syncing.style.transition = 'opacity 0.5s ease';
      syncing.style.opacity = '0';
      done.style.opacity = '0.3';
      uploadBtn.textContent = 'Done!';
      input.value = '';
    }, 5000);
  }
});
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400);
.frame {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  margin-top: -200px;
  margin-left: -200px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  box-shadow: 4px 8px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  background: linear-gradient(to top right, #3A92AF 0%, #5CA05A 100%);
  color: #676767;
  font-family: "Open Sans", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

.container {
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  height: 260px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 8px 10px 15px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.title {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #676767;
  line-height: 50px;
}

.line {
  position: relative;
  width: 0px;
  height: 3px;
  top: 49px;
  left: 0;
  background: #6ECE3B;
}

.line.active {
  animation: progressFill 5s ease-out forwards;
}

@keyframes progressFill {
  from {
    width: 0;
  }
  to {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

.dropzone {
  visibility: show;
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 100px;
  height: 80px;
  border: 1px dashed #676767;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.dropzone.dragover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.upload {
  position: absolute;
  width: 60px;
  opacity: 0.3;
}

.input {
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}

.filename {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.syncing {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 25px);
  left: calc(50% - 25px);
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  animation: rotate 2s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes rotate {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

.done {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

.upload-btn {
  position: relative;
  top: 180px;
  left: 80px;
  width: 140px;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #6ECE3B;
  border-radius: 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 14px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 0 0 #498C25;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.upload-btn:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 2px 0 0 #498C25, 0 2px 10px 0 #6ECE3B;
}
```

```html
<div class="frame">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="title">Drop file to upload</div>
    <div class="line"></div>
    <div class="dropzone">
      <svg class="upload" viewBox="0 0 640 512" width="100" title="cloud-upload-alt">
        <path d="M537.6 226.6c4.1-10.7 6.4-22.4 6.4-34.6 0-53-43-96-96-96-19.7 0-38.1 6-53.3 16.2C367 64.2 315.3 32 256 32c-88.4 0-160 71.6-160 160 0 2.7.1 5.4.2 8.1C40.2 219.8 0 273.2 0 336c0 79.5 64.5 144 144 144h368c70.7 0 128-57.3 128-128 0-61.9-44-113.6-102.4-125.4zM393.4 288H328v112c0 8.8-7.2 16-16 16h-48c-8.8 0-16-7.2-16-16V288h-65.4c-14.3 0-21.4-17.2-11.3-27.3l105.4-105.4c6.2-6.2 16.4-6.2 22.6 0l105.4 105.4c10.1 10.1 2.9 27.3-11.3 27.3z" />
            </svg>
      <span class="filename"></span>
      <input type="file" class="input">
    </div>
    <div class="upload-btn">Upload file</div>
    <svg class="syncing" viewBox="0 0 512 512" width="100" title="circle-notch">
    <path d="M288 39.056v16.659c0 10.804 7.281 20.159 17.686 23.066C383.204 100.434 440 171.518 440 256c0 101.689-82.295 184-184 184-101.689 0-184-82.295-184-184 0-84.47 56.786-155.564 134.312-177.219C216.719 75.874 224 66.517 224 55.712V39.064c0-15.709-14.834-27.153-30.046-23.234C86.603 43.482 7.394 141.206 8.003 257.332c.72 137.052 111.477 246.956 248.531 246.667C393.255 503.711 504 392.788 504 256c0-115.633-79.14-212.779-186.211-240.236C302.678 11.889 288 23.456 288 39.056z" />
    </svg>
    <svg class="done" viewBox="0 0 512 512" width="100" title="check-circle">
    <path d="M504 256c0 136.967-111.033 248-248 248S8 392.967 8 256 119.033 8 256 8s248 111.033 248 248zM227.314 387.314l184-184c6.248-6.248 6.248-16.379 0-22.627l-22.627-22.627c-6.248-6.249-16.379-6.249-22.628 0L216 308.118l-70.059-70.059c-6.248-6.248-16.379-6.248-22.628 0l-22.627 22.627c-6.248 6.248-6.248 16.379 0 22.627l104 104c6.249 6.249 16.379 6.249 22.628.001z" />
    </svg>


  </div>
</div>
```

this is what i tried to click everywhere in the dropzone :
`dropzone.addEventListener("click", () => { input.click();  });`

Comment: have you tried adding a console log into those to see if it is hitting the onClick?

Comment: I think the issue might be that you have 2 onClick listeners as well, I ran your code without the extra one and it worked; I'm assuming the extra listener was meant to be on your button instead.

Comment: Thanks ! I removed the second listener and it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem with your current button behavior is caused by overlapping elements.

Currently, the svg icons are reducing the "hit-box" as they are overlapping the desired drop zone. You can apply CSS property `pointer-events:none` to let pointer events pass through these top elements and trigger the invisible `<input>` element.

Besides you have 2 click events attached to the file input field.

```js
// Variables
const dropzone = document.querySelector('.dropzone');
const filenameDisplay = document.querySelector('.filename');
const input = document.querySelector('.input');
const uploadBtn = document.querySelector('.upload-btn');
const syncing = document.querySelector('.syncing');
const done = document.querySelector('.done');
const upload = document.querySelector('.upload');
const line = document.querySelector('.line');


dropzone.addEventListener("dragover", (e) => {
  //e.preventDefault();
  //e.stopPropagation();
    dropzone.classList.add("dragover");
});

dropzone.addEventListener("dragleave", () => {
  dropzone.classList.remove("dragover");
});

dropzone.addEventListener("drop", (e) => {
  //e.preventDefault();
  //e.stopPropagation();
  dropzone.classList.remove("dragover");
  //handleFiles(e.dataTransfer.files);
});

dropzone.addEventListener("dragenter", (e) => {
  //e.preventDefault();
  //e.stopPropagation();
  dropzone.classList.add("dragover");
});

input.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
  const files = event.target.files;
  if (files.length > 0) {
    const fileName = files[0].name;
    document.querySelector('.filename').textContent = fileName;
    upload.style.display = 'none';
  }
});


uploadBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const files = document.querySelector('.input').files;
  if (files.length > 0) {  
    dropzone.style.transition = 'opacity 0.5s ease';
    syncing.style.transition = 'opacity 1s ease';
    dropzone.style.opacity = '0';
    syncing.style.opacity = '0.3';
    line.classList.add('active');
    uploadBtn.textContent = 'Uploading...';

    setTimeout(() => {
            done.style.transition = 'opacity 1s ease';
            syncing.style.transition = 'opacity 0.5s ease';
      syncing.style.opacity = '0';
        done.style.opacity = '0.3';
            uploadBtn.textContent = 'Done!';
            input.value = ''; 
    }, 5000); 
  }
});
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400);
.frame {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  margin-top: -200px;
  margin-left: -200px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  box-shadow: 4px 8px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  background: linear-gradient(to top right, #3A92AF 0%, #5CA05A 100%);
  color: #676767;
  font-family: "Open Sans", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

.container {
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  height: 260px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 8px 10px 15px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.title {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #676767;
  line-height: 50px;
}

.line {
  position: relative;
  width: 0px;
  height: 3px;
  top: 49px;
  left: 0;
  background: #6ECE3B;
}

.line.active {
  animation: progressFill 5s ease-out forwards;
}

@keyframes progressFill {
  from {
    width: 0;
  }
  to {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

.dropzone {
  visibility: visible;
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 100px;
  height: 80px;
  border: 1px dashed #676767;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.dropzone.dragover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.upload {
  position: absolute;
  width: 60px;
  opacity: 0.3;
}

.input {
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}

.filename {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.syncing {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 25px);
  left: calc(50% - 25px);
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  animation: rotate 2s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes rotate {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

.done {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

.upload-btn {
  position: relative;
  top: 180px;
  left: 80px;
  width: 140px;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #6ECE3B;
  border-radius: 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 14px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 0 0 #498C25;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.upload-btn:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 2px 0 0 #498C25, 0 2px 10px 0 #6ECE3B;
}


/* make sure the input el is on top */

.input {
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 999;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input::-webkit-file-upload-button {
  cursor: pointer;
}


/* disable pointer events for overlaying svgs */

svg {
  pointer-events: none
}
```

```html
<div class="frame">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="title">Drop file to upload</div>
    <div class="line"></div>
    <div class="dropzone">
      <svg class="upload" viewBox="0 0 640 512" width="100" title="cloud-upload-alt">
        <path d="M537.6 226.6c4.1-10.7 6.4-22.4 6.4-34.6 0-53-43-96-96-96-19.7 0-38.1 6-53.3 16.2C367 64.2 315.3 32 256 32c-88.4 0-160 71.6-160 160 0 2.7.1 5.4.2 8.1C40.2 219.8 0 273.2 0 336c0 79.5 64.5 144 144 144h368c70.7 0 128-57.3 128-128 0-61.9-44-113.6-102.4-125.4zM393.4 288H328v112c0 8.8-7.2 16-16 16h-48c-8.8 0-16-7.2-16-16V288h-65.4c-14.3 0-21.4-17.2-11.3-27.3l105.4-105.4c6.2-6.2 16.4-6.2 22.6 0l105.4 105.4c10.1 10.1 2.9 27.3-11.3 27.3z" />
            </svg>
      <span class="filename"></span>
      <input type="file" class="input">
    </div>
    <div class="upload-btn">Upload file</div>
    <svg class="syncing" viewBox="0 0 512 512" width="100" title="circle-notch">
    <path d="M288 39.056v16.659c0 10.804 7.281 20.159 17.686 23.066C383.204 100.434 440 171.518 440 256c0 101.689-82.295 184-184 184-101.689 0-184-82.295-184-184 0-84.47 56.786-155.564 134.312-177.219C216.719 75.874 224 66.517 224 55.712V39.064c0-15.709-14.834-27.153-30.046-23.234C86.603 43.482 7.394 141.206 8.003 257.332c.72 137.052 111.477 246.956 248.531 246.667C393.255 503.711 504 392.788 504 256c0-115.633-79.14-212.779-186.211-240.236C302.678 11.889 288 23.456 288 39.056z" />
    </svg>
    <svg class="done" viewBox="0 0 512 512" width="100" title="check-circle">
    <path d="M504 256c0 136.967-111.033 248-248 248S8 392.967 8 256 119.033 8 256 8s248 111.033 248 248zM227.314 387.314l184-184c6.248-6.248 6.248-16.379 0-22.627l-22.627-22.627c-6.248-6.249-16.379-6.249-22.628 0L216 308.118l-70.059-70.059c-6.248-6.248-16.379-6.248-22.628 0l-22.627 22.627c-6.248 6.248-6.248 16.379 0 22.627l104 104c6.249 6.249 16.379 6.249 22.628.001z" />
    </svg>


  </div>
</div>
```

The above snippets removes the dropzone click events and instead puts the invisible input field on top via `z-index`.

Also check dev tools for invalid property values such as `visibility: show`

Comment: Thanks ! It works as I expected but I didn't understand your last sentence. Did you mean that "visibility: visible" is invalid ?

Comment: Sorry I meant `visibility: show`. All in all dev tools are always helpful to find errors in CSS - even if these just help to make the CSS more readable (e.g by removing rules/properties without any effect)